# Messenger with multiple buses

Tags: symfony

I have multiple buses

```
framework:
    messenger:
        default_bus: messenger.bus.command
        buses:
            messenger.bus.command: ~
            messenger.bus.query: ~
```

In my unit tests I have something like that

```
$this->commandBus = static::$container->get('messenger.bus.command');
```

I get

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
>   The "messenger.bus.command" service or alias has been removed or
>   inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it
>   public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency
>   injection instead.

How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 4.1 adds the '[test container](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-simpler-service-testing)', that allows access to what would otherwise be private services. However, you will also need to explicitly [make the service public](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/alias_private.html) (at least within your test-environment), so it is not removed.

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    test.messenger.bus.command:
        alias: messenger.bus.command
        public: true

class AddUserCommandTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private function assertUserCreated()
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        // gets the special container that allows fetching private services
        $container = self::$container;

        $this->assertTrue(self::$container->get('security.password_encoder')->isPasswordValid($user, '...');
        // ...
}
```